# Peas with onions

Tags: pot, pan-fry

I was wondering whether it is best to cook peas with onions in a pan or in a pot. Is there any difference between the two approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a few details about the dish, please? Are you talking about fresh or dried peas, for example?

Comment: I'm not sure the cookware is going to make a great deal of difference, in & of itself. You need to give us more to work with; your prep, method & how it would differ between the two pan types...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is that frying or sauté pans usually have larger cooking surfaces and will aid in evaporating liquid more quickly compare to pots

if you use fresh peas it should not have any benefit one way or the other, but if you use frozen peas, then they will have more humidity (liquid) and using a pan might make cooking the peas easier.

I probably have done peas with onions in both pans and pots many times and have not seen much difference to make me choose one over the other.